# Definition of $L^p$ space and almost everywhere defined functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $(\Omega, M, \mu)$ a measure space, one defines $L^p$ to be the quotient of the set of all measurable functions $f$ from $\Omega$ to the extended real line such that $|f|^p$ has finite integral, with respect to, $~$ the the 'almost everywhere equal' equivalence relation.

I cannot understand why it is a vector space. Take $f,g$ in $L^p$. Their sum is defined as the equivalence class of the sum of any two representatives $h,k$ of respectively $f$ and $g$. $h,k$ are functions defined on $\Omega$, and are almost everywhere finite, however their sum may be only almost everywhere defined. So what do do?

I guess one could extend $h+k$ on all of the domain by just setting to $0$ (or any other value) the sum every time it is not defined. This would still yield a well defined sum of equivalence classes. But for the integral? Can I define the integral of an almost everywhere defined function to be the integral of the function on the set on which it is defined?

Answer (score 3):

The representatives are defined everywhere, but we say that two are the same if they are not necessarily equal, but equal almost everywhere. The sum of two representatives is again defined everywhere, but we need to know that if $f\simeq a$ and $g\simeq b$ then $f+g\simeq a+b$. Both $f+g$ and $a+b$ are defined everywhere, and they are equal almost everywhere.

There may be a time when we want to say that a function is only defined almost everywhere, but that's because we don't care what it's equal to on a set of measure $0$ if we know what it is everywhere else. We could define it arbitrarily and it wouldn't affect the equivalence class. We can still sum two such functions. We can either define them arbitrarily on the undefined portion, or we can say that the undefined portion expands, but it is still of measure $0$.

Comment: Say I have two classes, let's choose two representatives: they're defined everywhere. Now let's sum them and create the class of the sum. This is as far as I know the definition of the sum of classes, and it is independent of the choice of the two representatives, but is the sum of representatives always defined? Maybe I just don't understand how the sum of class is defined in the first place.

Comment: @Leo It's just the pointwise sum of the two functions.

Comment: These functions take values on the extended real line, what if one is $+\infty$ and the other one $-\infty$ at a certain point?

Comment: @Leo Then I guess it will fail to be defined there. I don't see the point of using the extended real line if everything is integrable anyway.

Comment: I was trying to understand the theory as presented during my lectures, which only covers everywhere defined functions while allowing $\infty - \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

To show that h+k is integrable its suffice to observe that $|h+k|^p \leq 2^p(|h|^p+|k|^p)$. For the last part of your question the answer is affirmative. Suppose without loss of generality that your function $f$ is positive (otherwise write $f=f^+-f^-$). Now suppose that f is well defined on $A\subseteq \Omega$ and $\mu(A^c)=0$ and $f=\infty$ on $A^c$ (thats the only case since f is positive and f is defined in $\Omega$). Then since f is positive you can write  $\int_{\Omega}fd\mu=\int_{A}fd\mu+\int_{A^c}fd\mu=\int_{A}fd\mu+\infty \cdot 0$, and now in measure theory we accept that $0\cdot \infty=0$. So you get that $\int_{\Omega}fd\mu=\int_{A}fd\mu$

Comment: Can you please correct the typo?

Comment: Sorry am writing from my cellphone.

Comment: Thanks! So the set of p-integrable functions (not $L^p$) is a vector space with a modified sum of functions (that accounts for $+\infty-\infty$, for example by doing what I said in the question), and then the sum in $L^p$ will be the class of the modified sum of two representatives: as you said this won't affect the integral since we're speaking of zero measure sets. Correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. The only reason we are dealing with equivalent classes is because $(\int_{\Omega}|f|^pd\mu)^{1/p}$ defines a norm.

Answer (score 1):

Take functions that are zero almost everywhere. It is a vector subspace of the space of all p-integrable functions, right? So you take the quotient space (all p-integrable functions   by functions zero a.e.). That's $L_p$.

Comment: Ok, but the usual sum of function doesn't work, since it doesn't always yield a function defined everywhere, right? So technically the set of all p-integrable functions is not a vector space with the usual sum