# Essentially bounded functions in $L^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d)$ and their definition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

Given a function $f\in L^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d)$. If a consider the following Cauchy problem:

$$
\dot{y}(t) = f(t), \quad \text{for almost every } t \in [0,1].
$$
I want to understand, why often we do not speak of the value of $f$ at each time instant $t \in [0,1]$.

For example, in this case, we can't write $f(\frac{1}{2})$. And from what I have seen in some textbooks, that it requires to use the notion of Lebesgue point in order to write $f(a)$ (with $a$ is a Lebesgue point).

Can we also say that $f$ is defined (only) almost everywhere?

Definition of a Lebesgue point: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_de_Lebesgue

Comment: Maybe this other post might help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3428502/1104384